# What to do in ketu mahadasha?

Tags: vedas, mantras, astrology, parashara, horary-astrology

I really need help in overcoming my situations from which I am suffering. I am in very much debt. One day I must be killed by someone or commit suicide right now I am jobless. I am the only person for taking care of my family. Before 2 years I was living a good life. My name is Ved Parkash dob-05/05/1986 time 04:00 am place: Bhilai, Chattisgarh. Begging for help.

Comment: If you are really sure that Ketu is the one creating problems, then read Ketu Stotram, Ketu Kavacham, worship Lord Ganesha (over ruling deity for Ketu) or recite any of his Stotrams. Take help of Lal Kitab remedies for Ketu (these are not traditional or scriptural remedies but highly effective). You can get all of these from Google.

Comment: Check the remedies for Ketu from here ---- https://www.astrojyoti.com/mantras2.htm

Comment: Some more remedies for Ketu --- https://www.astroshastra.com/articles/lalkitabketu.php

Answer (score 1):

I am going to tell you the general remedy to get rid of the bad effects of Ketu dosha or overcoming ketu dasha. To know the impact of Ketu in one's life, It is important to analyze the person's horoscope chart. First of all, Ketu is a natural malefic planet but not always brings bad to a person.

Ketu is often called as Mokshakaraka. As per Vimshottari dasha system, Ketu dasa will be 7 years in a person's life. Ketu brings a significant changes in anyone's life during dasha or antardhasa period. It depends on the planetary position in horoscope chart while birth and current planetary position(Gochara). It also depends on the aspect of other planets on ketu or the house where ketu sits in a horoscope chart.

One thing we have to remember is that a planet will never give good/bad results thought its dasa or antardasa period.

Lord Ganesha is the adhidevata for the planet ketu. So, worshipping Lord Ganesha on every Saturday can satisfy ketu to avoid malefic effects.

Many astrologers warn the people not to have ketu related things with us during ketu dasha or any planets dasha like wearing Gems, metals associated with that. This is absolutely wrong statement. Even they are Maharishi Parasara says like that. He never talked about this in his Brihat hora shastra or somewhere.

Im speaking in general, If someone consume or donate the dhaanya associated to that planet, It will significantly reduce the bad effects of the planet if we do this with bhakthi and dedication. For Ketu, the person should consume/donate horse gram on Saturday brings a lot of good changes.

As per Ketu's karagatva, It is a mokshakaraga. Being humble and refrain from the materialistic world itself a great remedy to get rid of bad impact of the planet Ketu.

Recite Ganesha Pancharatna Sloka, Gayathri. Perform Ganapathy Homa at least during Ganesha Chaturthi or Sankranthi or Hastha Nakshathra. Refer panchangam for more details.

Chanting Navagraha peeta hara storta is also a right sloka to get rid of bad effects of planets positioned in one's horoscope.

https://rkkrishnaa.in/2019/05/navagraha-peedahara-stotram/

Worship Nagadevathe idol installed under Banyan/Neem tree in ganesha temple. Practice meditation.

Helping poor people as much we can reduce the malefic impacts of a planet.